# how to generate Google Map Api Premier unique signature?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have a commercial application that is using google map (not static map) and GPS. I have Google map api premier client id and cryptographic key to use google map. But not able to generate google map api key (unique signature). I am using https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/#GettingKeys

as reference to get key. 
But not getting success.

Answer (score 1):

try this link : [how to get an api key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Here's an example of a Keytool command that generates an MD5 certificate fingerprint for the key alias_name in the keystore my-release-key.keystore:

**$ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore**

Keytool will prompt you to enter passwords for the keystore and key. As output of the command, Keytool prints the fingerprint to the shell. For example:

Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98

Once you have the fingerprint, you can go to the Maps API registration site: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: It doesn't work for paid applications. i need explanation of key generation for Google map API premier.

Comment: Please post some link or reference for generation of of Google Map API Premier Key.